# Selector, in listview (swipe-listview) row, stays in state pressed after re-instanciating the adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-selector

I have a listview and the row's layout has a child with the background set to the following selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/pressed_panel" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_panel_corners" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_panel_corners" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

And now this scenario happens:

1. I instantiate the adapter and set it to the listview, with an underlying list, let's say model A (inside a ListFragment)
2. I press on the first row (happens for other row also), and only while pressed, the selector stays in the pressed state, showing some gray color, duh!
3. I select from a menu some item and that triggers: creating a new instance of the adaptor, with list model B, and apply it to the listview.
4. **And now the problem**: the first row has the selector in the pressed state

---

More info:
@Questions raised by Abhishek V in comment:
1. Background is set to row layout's child and not the row layout itself right? Right! Here is the layout, the selector is set to the relative with id "container_conversation"

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_select_row"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_round_selector"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="8dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
            <SomeViews>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/front"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_conversation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_panel">
                <SomeViews>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/unread_indicator"
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_circle"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

2) Click/touch listener is set to row layout or it's child?
Child
3) Which listener you are using, is it onClick, onTouch or onItemClick?
The listview is actually copied from the library android-swipelistview https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview .
The click that does the damage is set as follows:

```
frontView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            swipeListView.onClickFrontView(downPosition);
        }
    });
```

and this click goes notifying this listener

```
BaseSwipeListViewListener swipeListener = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClickFrontView(int position) {

    }//...
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you show the `Adapter` and `XML Selector` maybe we will catch something

Comment: May not solve the problem, but walk over all the children and set their press state to false `setPressed(false)`. If it is recycling the views in the listview, one of them might not have got the equivalent of `mouseUp` before it lost its focus.

Comment: can you give us some more info - 1) Background is set to row layout's `child` and not the row layout itself right?  2) Click/touch listener is set to row layout or it's child?. 3) Which listener you are using, is it `onClick`, `onTouch` or `onItemClick`?

Comment: @Chris I tried setPressed(false) on the view in getView() in adapter, didn't work.

Comment: @Abhishek V  i'll update the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing has been reported here https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/41.

As per the cooment by @strgev in that thread, the fix is to -

edit class `SwipeListViewTouchListener` by adding the line below to onTouch method:

```
....
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
...
```

can you try that?

Comment: GREAT! Congrats for the bounty! Thank you alot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with `clearChoices` and `notifyDataSetChanged`:

```
yourListView.clearChoices();
yourListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: thank you but it didn't work, I actually have choiceMode="none" on the list

Comment: try making it "single"

Answer (score 0):

It may be a [**mutate** problem](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html). Try to assign the background to the row programmatically by first calling `mutate()` on the drawable.

First, obtain a `Drawable` instance from your custom selector-drawable, then invoke `mutate()` on it and finally assign the drawable as row's background:

```
Drawable selector = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selector)
selector.mutate();
//...
row.setBackground(selector);
```